# python function exception cannot be caught

Tags: python, function, exception, parameters

My code like this:

```
def retry(func, *args ):
     try:
        func(*args)
     except:
        print ""
```

I want to write a function to pass a function as parameter, but in the `retry` function, it always cannot catch the exception in the function which is passed in.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is your use case here?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write like this:

```
try:
    func(*args)
except:
    print ""
```

I'm sure it can catch all of your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def retry(func, *args ):
    try: func(*args)
    except SyntaxError: print ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If just printing an empty string, how will you know if the except clause is entered? Try this:

```
def exception_raising_function(a, b, c):
    print "exception_raising_function(): got args a = {!r}, b = {!r}, c = {!r}".format(a, b, c)
    return 1/0    # raises ZeroDivisionError

def retry(func, *args):
     try:
        return func(*args)
     except Exception as exc:
        print "retry(): got exception %s" % exc

>>> retry(exception_raising_function, 1, 2, 'three')
exception_raising_function(): got args a = 1, b = 2, c = 'three'
retry(): got exception integer division or modulo by zero
```

So that works and we know that it works because there is some output to prove it.

You seem to want to implement a retry function that retries calling a function if there was an exception, i.e. "retryable" exceptions. You could do this using a decorator, something like that discussed at http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/ might work for you.